# How can I express what I study?

Tags: grammar

how can I express properly what I study and in which year I actually am?

is the following correct:

```
I'am studying a bachelor in computer sciences, I'am in my third year.
```

I also tried  to translate what would I say in french, but it sounded silly to me :/.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not *I'am* but rather *I'm* or *I am*.

Comment: Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Note also that terminology may differ from place to place. In some U.S. institutions, you would conventionally be called be a *junior*, at others a *third-year student* or simply a *third-year*; at the military academies you would be a *second-class* cadet/midshipman. The shortest way to express it might be *I am a third-year undergraduate in computer science.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd say "I'm in my third year of studies *towards* a bachelor's in Computer Sciences" or something similar.  Note that it is a "bachelor's (degree)," not just "a bachelor."  Your phrase instead means you have your eye on an unmarried man in CS.

Comment: ... Ok I will never forget the ' ever.

Comment: ...Unless he actually is spending three years to study a single student in computer science.

Comment: Can I say: "I am studying in BA."?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu No, that is not idiomatic in English. You could say "I am pursuing a BA, " or "I am in a BA program."

Comment: Is "I am studying for a BA" fine?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu Yes "I am studying for a BA" is ok.

Answer (score 1):

A few examples

I am a third year student of **bachelor of science** in computer science. (If the broad category is kept)

I am a third year student of bachelor in **computer science**. (If the broad category is omitted)

I am studying in third year of my bachelor's degree (in computer science).

Answer (score 0):

I am 3rd year student taking up Bachelor of Science in Computer Science.

I'm 3rd year,and I'm studying COMPSCI.